# Get featured image from post on RSS feed

Tags: post-thumbnails, rss, the-content

I want to add the featured image to my RSS feed.

```
function rss_post_thumbnail($content) {

    global $post;

    if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
        $content = '<p>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID) . '</p>' . get_the_content();
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'rss_post_thumbnail', 20, 1);
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'rss_post_thumbnail', 20, 1);
```

With this snippet the thumbnail is shown, but the content is not generated correct. It is shown with shortcodes and its not formatted...

When i use the snippet below, where i remove the ordering of filters, the content is shown, but the featured image is missing:

```
function rss_post_thumbnail($content) {

    global $post;

    if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
        $content = '<p>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID) . '</p>' . get_the_content();
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'rss_post_thumbnail');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'rss_post_thumbnail');
```

Comment: "With this snippet the thumbnail is shown, but the content is not generated correct." - you're building the output from get_the_content() not $content, and I'd guess the latter has the shortcodes expanded (via the 'the_content' filter). I can't explain the second behaviour though.

Comment: Note also that the_content_feed takes two arguments, $content and $feed_type, not 1 as you've got in your first add_filter.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the right solution:

```
function rss_post_thumbnail($content) {

    global $post;

    if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
        $output = '<p>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID) . '</p>';
    }
    return $output . $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'rss_post_thumbnail', 20, 1);
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'rss_post_thumbnail', 20, 1);
```

Comment: If there's no thumbnail then you're using $output without setting in though, which will trigger a 'Notice' in debug mode.